# Dynamically loading files with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that loads a `.js` file from the filesystem, validates it against a given structure, and returns this structure if successful; otherwise, an exception is thrown. The function expects a path as input.

So far I've done this in plain JavaScript by loading the file with `require`, checking the result with a JSON schema, and if all was well, returning the contents.

Now I'm trying to build the same thing in TypeScript. The problem is that `require` gives me "something" back at first – it may or it may not fit the expected structure. So in this sense it's of type `any`.

The question now is: Should I stick with the JSON schema approach, and after the successful validation convert things into a suitable type? This seems to me somehow unneeded complex, because 90% of the JSON schema only checks things the type system would do for me: Whether certain properties are set, the types are correct, …

Nevertheless I get only `any` back from the `require` call – and a cast does not help me at this point, because all the type information is only available at compile time, but loading is only done at runtime.

How could I solve this issue in an elegant way?

Comment: Why can't you just `import` the files? Or do they have to be loaded dynamically? In that case you can probably run `tsc` from your code.

Comment: They have to be loaded dynamically, because they act as some kind of plugins for a server, which can be written by the user. So when loading them, I don't know what's there, whether it's correct, and so on … and it *has* to happen at runtime (and I didn't want to carry `tsc` as a real dependency with me).

Comment: Wait ... you want to compile TS at runtime without a compiler? Or what am I missunderstanding here?

Comment: No. I just want to dynamically load a .js file at runtime, verify its structure and use it. And my question is how to best make the transition between loading (which returns any) and using it (where I‘d like to be typed). I know the type structure I expect, but I have to figure out at runtime whether what I actually get matches what I expect - and if so, convert any to a given type. The question is how to perform this in an elegant way.

Comment: Oh well then ... `verify(code: any): code is SomeType { ... }` ...

Comment: Is this meant to be code?